# blockquote breaking in the middle

Tags: 7, theming

When I post something with long blockquote, that's OK, but when this post appeared on front page, it's breaking is such way, that no one can guess that there are also a continuation of the post.

For example, the post: http://en.nuclear-plant.org/node/23

Front page: http://en.nuclear-plant.org/

How to solve this? How to give a hint to readers, how to make "Read more" label more visible?

I don't want to add <!--break--> to each post, because, I have very long quotations, and want to fold them.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7, the default is to use an excerpt (i.e. a trimmed value) of the full text as the *summary*. The summary is the text that is placed on the front page.

If I understand your question correctly, you do not want to use the default excerpt, because this confuses the reader.

Instead of this default, you can type in whatever you want as the summary to appear on the front page, e.g.:

> Here is a long and quite interesting quote about lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  To read the full text, just click on the  **Read more** link below.

To add a hand-written summary, click in the "(Edit summary)" link just above the main body text field in the input form.  Leave this field blank to use the trimmed value of full text as the summary.